# (SQL) Select rows only where a column's values are found in another column?

Tags: sql, pointers, select, filter, reference

Is it possible to filter rows where one column only has values that match ones found in another column, but without using subselect?

Ex:

[All rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDezt.png)

[Selected rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/So4Y1.png)

Filtered to only rows with column values that were referenced in the pointer column.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by doing an INNER JOIN with the same table, matching the value of the different columns and keeping the results unique with DISTINCT (since there could be more than one pointers to the same name):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM mytable a INNER JOIN mytable b ON a.name = b.pointer
```

Comment: Why the need for an Inner Join?
Why not just make it a condition? E.g. WHERE name = pointer

Answer (score -1):

Here You Go, using selg join:

```
Create table #temp( name varchar(200), ColumnA int, PointerColumnB int)

Insert into #temp values('NAMEA',1,null),('NAMEB',2,3),
('NAMEC',3,3),('NAMED',4,null),('NAMEE',5,4),('NAMEF',6,7),('NAMEG',7,null)

Select distinct x.Name
from #temp x
join #temp y on x.ColumnA = y.PointerColumnB
```